# Método con igual resultado que ngFor pero en la consola

Tags: angular

¿Qué método es igual al ngFor en angular para poder ver lo mismo en la consola?

Comment: Y no podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que esperas conseguir?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Muchas, gracias. Ya resolví el problema. Con la respuesta de Nestdan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la directiva Angular ngFor es capaz de representar a una lista de elementos en la vista soporta muchas opciones por ejemplo para acceder al indice seleccionar al primero o al ultimo elemento y asociar un color distinto segun sea par o impar su ubicación y otras
Sea

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios">
    <td> {{usuario.id}}</td>
      <td>{{usuario.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table> 

interface usuario{
    id:number;
    name:string
}
```

Si quisieramos ver por consola la propiedad name y id

```
let usuarios:usuario[]=[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'bill'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'ted'
    }
]
usuarios.map((usuario:usuario)=>
console.log('usuario id:', usuario.id,'name:',usuario.name))
```

El indice con:

```
usuarios.map((usuario:usuario,index:number)=>
console.log('usuario id:', usuario.id,'name:',usuario.name,'indice',index))
```

también en la consola del navegador chrome podrás ver distintos estilos
directiva "%c" para aplicar un estilo CSS a la salida de la consola:

```
console.log("%cMy stylish message", "color: red; font-style: italic");
```

[estilos consola](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Eso es lo que estaba buscando

Comment: Ahora tengo otro problema.  Yo quiero saber cómo mostrar en una tabla el usuario que creo un producto. Ya yo recibo la repuesta con el objeto completo, o sea producto  con un objeto que tienen nombre y id de usuario. Pero no se como puedo mostrar el nombre del usuario en la tabla.

Comment: recibís esto? producto1={"creo":{"nombre":'juan',"id":4}} si no nos muestras la estructura de lo que recibís es imposible decir algo También ya hiciste un pregunta si la misma fue respondida hay que cerrarla admitiendo alguna respuesta porque otro vera tu pregunta y quizás la conteste sin saber que ya fue respondida

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya resolví con la respuesta que me envió nestdan y sobre la segunda pregunta era que en la interface del producto, había declarado el Objeto que correspondía al usuario como un string.

Comment: Si en otras preguntas que hagas lo mejor es escribir el código así te podrán ayudar simplemente copias el codigo lo pintas!!! y seleccionas {} que significa ejemplo con codigo a veces hay que hacerlo dos o tres veces  para que lo tome como codigo pero al final te quedara el codigo para que lo vea cualquiera saludos